# error with name or value of a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I have a weird error with name of my variable :

- when i try to call function `map.removeLayer($scope.pimp.init.carte.layers[key].name);`, it's doesnt works (no error, but action is not performed)
- when i put manually `map.removeLayer(markersLayer_2);` it's good, `markersLayer_2` is the value of $scope.pimp.init.carte.layers[key].name, and the action is performed

i don't why this difference, because with alert(); or console.log(); , `$scope.pimp.init.carte.layers[key].name` returns the good value (`markersLayer_2`).

Why i can't use $scope of angularjs in this leaflet function ?

Comment: Where are you executing that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `removeLayer` expects an instance of `L.Layer`, not the `name` property of that instance. Try: `map.removeLayer($scope.pimp.init.carte.layers[key]);` What you are doing now is using a string as the parameter. That won't work. You need to use the actual instance.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer